# Smooth scroll div to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a smooth scroll with the anchor and its work perfectly. But this JS is conflict to the plugin that I use, so I need to change the script.

I want is instead of an anchor, I want to use a div. But I don't know how doing this.

Note: There's an a href where link to a different page.

Here's the script that I'm currently using.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname){
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
});
```

Example html that I need (I don't know if the html is in correct format):

```
<div id="#test"></div>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Updated:

Here's the code from answer below

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('[data-anchor]').click(function(){
var target = $($(this).data('anchor'));
    if (target.length){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
});
```

That code is working, but when the div has a link that pointed to another page, the code is not working.

Example html:

```
<div data-anchor="/testEnvironment/how-can-i-get-a-loan/#whocangetaloan"></div>
```

This html is place to different page

```
<section id="#whocangetaloan"></section>
```

Comment: Show the HTML too, please.

Comment: For transient readers - last bit of the question got solved by using normal `a` tags for external links. The code with data attributes will make same page smoothscroll possible and leave these regular links alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to have divs instead of links, a data attribute could be used to provide the anchor info. The markup would look something like this:

```
<header>
  <div id="menu">
    <div data-anchor="#home">Home</div>
    <div data-anchor="#about">About</div>
    <div data-anchor="#services">Services</div>
    <div data-anchor="#projects">Projects</div>
    <div data-anchor="#contact">Contact</div>
  </div>
</header>

<section id="home"></section>
<section id="about"></section>
<section id="services"></section>
<section id="projects"></section>
<section id="contact"></section>
```

And this script will then implement the animation :

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('[data-anchor]').click(function() {

    var target = $($(this).data('anchor'));

    if (target.length) {

    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    }
});
});
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmaYLp?editors=001)

This will make `a` tags no longer needed to smoothly scroll to an anchor on the page. Links to an *external* page and anchor can now be used normally without the original script conflicting in any way.